# If all fields on Form successfully validate, page crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to take the data entered from a Form component of the data entered in a Modal component. I've crafted a handleSubmit after what I've seen in the react-bootstrap documentation, which seems to crash the page if everything successfully validates. However, if I leave one field unvalidated, everything functions as intended.

I've tried changing the types of data being validated, altering my handleSubmit etc.

```
 export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      validated: false,
      file: null,
      store: "Target",
      pdf: true,
      price: 1.00,
      category: "Supplies",
      date: "01/01/2019",
      description: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  add = id => {
    this.props.add(this.state.pdf,this.state.store, this.state.date, this.state.price, this.state.category, this.state.description);
  };
  handleSubmit(event) {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Failed");
      }
        this.setState({validated: true})
        this.props.add(this.state.pdf,this.state.store, this.state.date, this.state.price, this.state.category,this.state.description );

  }
```

Continuing on, the layout of my Form is as follows:

```
render() {
    const { validated } = this.state;
    const divStyle2 = {
      padding: "1em"
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <h4>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileInvoiceDollar} />
          
        </h4>

        <div style={divStyle2}>
          <Nav variant="pills" activeKey="/home" expand="lg">
            <Nav.Item>
              <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title> </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Form
                  noValidate
                  validated={validated}
                  onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
                >
                  <Container>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="4" controlId="file">
                        <Form.Label>Receipt File*</Form.Label>
                        <Button variant="outline-dark">
                          <div className="files">
                            <Files
                              className="files-dropzone"
                              onChange={this.onFilesChange}
                              onError={this.onFilesError}
                              accepts={["image/png", ".pdf"]}
                              multiple
                              maxFiles={3}
                              maxFileSize={10000000}
                              minFileSize={0}
                              clickable
                            >
                              Browse
                            </Files>
                          </div>
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="vendor">
                        <Form.Label>Vendor/Retailer*</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="" required value={this.state.store} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                          Please provide a vendor/retailer.
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="date">
                        <Form.Label>Transaction date*</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="date" placeholder="" required value={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                          Please provide a date.
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="price">
                        <Form.Label>Receipt total ($USD)*</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                          type="number"
                          placeholder="0.00"
                          required
                          value={this.state.price} 
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                          Please provide a valid price.
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="category">
                        <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="" required value={this.state.category} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                          Please provide a valid category.
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="description">
                        <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="" size="lg" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="submit">
                        <Button
                          variant="outline-dark"
                          type="cancel"
                          onClick={this.handleClose}
                        >
                          Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          variant="outline-dark"
                          type="submit"
                          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                        >
                           
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                  </Container>
                </Form>

                <Modal.Footer />
              </Modal>

              <Button variant="outline-dark" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                {" "}
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />  
              </Button>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item className="justify-content-end">
              <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
                Report Total: ${this.props.total}
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It's expected that if everything is successfully validated, the program continues normally. Instead, it crashes and reloads the whole web page. I have tried taking out the this.props.add at the bottom of the handleSubmit, but get the same result- crash. It might be useful to note that somehow, add is being run twice and generating two components. However, I'm considering that a separate bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` outside of the if statement, such as:

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const form = event.currentTarget;
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        console.log("Failed");
      }
        this.setState({validated: true})
        this.props.add(this.state.pdf,this.state.store, this.state.date, this.state.price, this.state.category,this.state.description );

  }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!

It's strange that my original setup is what's in the Form documentation for bootstrap, which is to have these event functions run only inside of a failed validation. I thought it was weird but never thought to paste it outside.

Comment: The documentation was probably expressing a way to prevent the form from submitting if the validation failed (in any general case), but since you're using react and handling the submit actions through state management rather than posting the data, you want to stop it from actually submitting even if it is valid.